# Fixed height and repeating columns in menu - CSS

Tags: asp.net, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a menu where I want the menu to be of fixed height and want to render the menu vertically, rather than horizontally. i.e., I want the menu to carry on, after a certain height, in the next column, so that there are no empty spaces. Please have a look at this screenshot...

[image: Menu Screen shot]

I want the "Admission Desk" menu to be below "Patient" menu and the next one after that and so on..., so no empty spaces are shown...

Here is my CSS...

```
menurepository .submenudiv
{
    float: left;
    padding: 1px 3px 3px 2px;
    margin: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menurepository .submenudiv h3
{
    color: #111111;
    font-size: 6pt;
    float: left;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    text-align: left;
}
.linkdiv
{
    clear: both;
}
.menurepository .submenudiv .linkdiv a
{
    color: #28A1E2;
    font-size: 7pt;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Naveed Butt, is it possible for you to upload your dropdown menu in (jsfiddle)[http://jsfiddle.net/] so that we can have better clarity.

Comment: Here is the link on the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2LUYD/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this using the new css3 column-count rule [http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp]. This only works on Firefox/Chrome/Safari at this stage according to w3schools. For IE, the menu gracefully degrades to one long column. IE 10 might work, but I'm not able to verify that.

You'd need to simplify your markup to get the menu columns to work. See [http://jsfiddle.net/sSwpZ/] for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

[FTColumnflow](https://github.com/ftlabs/ftcolumnflow) provides a rather elegant solution to your problem.